# как в R заменить дубликаты

Tags: dataframe, vector, r

Подскажите пожалуйста как заменить дубликаты, которые при смене с 1 на -1 или с -1 на 1 повторяющийся заменить на (NA)

```
mas = c(1 , 1 , 1 , 1,  1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1 ,-1 ,-1 ,-1 ,-1 ,-1, -1, -1,  1,  1,  1,  1, -1, -1)
mas
[1]  1  1  1  1  1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1  1  1  1  1 -1 -1

duplicated(mas ) # не помогает


вот что должно получиться
[1]  1 NA NA NA NA -1 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA  1 NA NA NA -1 NA
```

Пробую вот таким способом, не получается.

```
mas = c(1 , 1 , 1 , 1,  1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1 ,-1 ,-1 ,-1 ,-1 ,-1, -1, -1,  1,  1,  1,  1, -1, -1)
mas
[1]  1  1  1  1  1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1  1  1  1  1 -1 -1

# вот такой способ, но пропускает первое число и выводит TRUE либо FALSE, а в целом работает. 
dt = data.table(mas)

dt2 = dt$mas[-1] != dt$mas[-nrow(dt)]
dt2
[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE


а вот что должно получиться
[1]  1 NA NA NA NA -1 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA  1 NA NA NA -1 NA
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если в качестве решения используется сравнение элемента вектора с его предыдущим элементом, то в качестве реализации можно применить функцию `shift` из пакета `data.table`:

```r
library(data.table)
idx <- fcoalesce(mas == shift(mas), FALSE)
mas[idx] <- NA
```

`fcoalesce` здесь заменяет `NA`, которое образуется при сравнении первого элемента вектора с предыдущего (которого нет).

Также можно отследить начало новой серии (одинаковых значений) с помощью функции `rle`:

```r
idx <- cumsum(c(1, rle(mas)$lengths))
mas[-idx] <- NA
```

`rle(mas)$lengths` возвращает длинну серии. Для получения индексов элементов, с которых начинается новая серия, используем кумулятивную сумму.

Результат:

```r
#  [1]  1 NA NA NA NA -1 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA  1 NA NA NA -1 NA
```

Comment: СПАСИБО! @Artem Klevtsov, очень помогли.